# TextArea overflowing [Codename One]

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

We have a app which involves posting new items.
Our testers have noticed that when typing in the TextAera the text scrolls to some degree, but then spills outside of the border of the component. 
I've included a screenshot of the issue with some details blurred; 
[image: screenshot of the issue]
You can see the text is overflowing outside the text area and covering the post button

Comment: is this an html page? thats why you call in textarea?

Comment: No, not it isn't. It's a Codename one app as indicated by the title and tags.

Comment: This looks like a bug.  Can you file an issue in the issue tracker and provide a test case.  This is does not occur in my current test suite, so a test case will likely be required to reproduce it  (it may be a combination of layout hierarchy and settings the result in this behaviour).

Comment: I've set up a simple example but this seems to only happen in very specific circumstances. I'll keep experimenting and see if I can work out a layout which causes this issue. I've actually seen it before on another app as well.
I have logged a bug report for a slightly different issue which may be related to this;  https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2085